# React + nvd3: 'querySelector' of undefined while running sample code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to integrate `nvd3` with `react`. When I am refreshing the page `node.js` fails with the following error:

> /home/nikita/project/node_modules/d3/d3.js:562
>       return n.querySelector(s);
>                ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined

I tested `nvd3` code without `react`, when it is presented as an `html` file and it is working fine, but now I want to integrate it with `react` and use `.jsx` files as views instead of plain `html`. The file that is rendered is the following one:

```
import React from 'react';
import DefaultLayout from './layouts/default';
import * as d3 from "d3";
import nvd3 from "nvd3";
require("./barChart.js");

class Index extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <DefaultLayout title={this.props.title}>
        <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>
        <div id="barChart">
            <svg styles={{height:'600px'}}/>
        </div>
      </DefaultLayout>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = Index;
```

The `barChart.js` looks like this:

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
import nvd3 from "nvd3";
var nv = nvd3;

 var barChart = nv.addGraph(function() {
        var chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart()
        .x(function(d) { return d.label })
        .y(function(d) { return d.value })
        .staggerLabels(true)
        //.staggerLabels(historicalBarChart[0].values.length > 8)
        .showValues(true)
        .duration(250)
        ;
    d3.select('#barChart svg')
        .datum(exampleData)
        .call(chart);
    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
    return chart;
});

//Each bar represents a single discrete quantity.
function exampleData() {
 return  [
{
  key: "Cumulative Return",
  values: [
    {
      "label" : "A Label" ,
      "value" : -29.765957771107
    } ,
    {
      "label" : "B Label" ,
      "value" : 0
    } ,
    {
      "label" : "C Label" ,
      "value" : 32.807804682612
    } ,
    {
      "label" : "D Label" ,
      "value" : 196.45946739256
    } ,
    {
      "label" : "E Label" ,
      "value" : 0.19434030906893
    } ,
    {
      "label" : "F Label" ,
      "value" : -98.079782601442
    } ,
    {
      "label" : "G Label" ,
      "value" : -13.925743130903
    } ,
    {
      "label" : "H Label" ,
      "value" : -5.1387322875705
    }
  ]
}
  ]

}

module.exports = barChart
```

Also, `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
"babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
"body-parser": "~1.18.2",
"cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
"d3": "^3.5.17",
"debug": "~2.6.9",
"express": "~4.15.5",
"express-react-views": "^0.10.4",
"mongodb": "^2.2.25",
"monk": "^4.0.0",
"morgan": "~1.9.0",
"react": "^16.2.0",
"react-dom": "^16.2.0",
"react-nvd3": "^0.5.7",
"serve-favicon": "~2.4.5"
},
```

I tried rewriting `barChart.js` as in the tutorial: https://medium.com/@Elijah_Meeks/interactive-applications-with-react-d3-f76f7b3ebc71
But no success. It is possible to eliminate the error, but the underlying reason for the issue - incorrect selection of a `DOM` element by `nvd3` - is not solved.

Comment: using `id` in react is kindoff a no go, the reason is the rendering of the virtual DOM and the comparison with the real DOM that will be messed up if you manipulate the dom from outside the reactjs rendering, other than that react also creates its own id's to make the comparison lighter. Find a way around it, check if `ref` callbacks can help you out

Comment: What are `ref` callbacks? Sorry I am new to react

Comment: You can look it up in the documentation here https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html , basically through the ref, you can save a rendered component so you can do some basic manipulations at a later time

Comment: OK, thanks. I tried using `class` property for `d3` selection, but it does not solve the issue

Comment: When does the callback get executed of your barchart? Note that if I see it correctly, your component will probably not be rendered at the time you require the barchart, but I don't really see where you invoke it

Comment: Seems like it is not executed. Should I somehow call it in the '.jsx' file? Before, when I just imported barChart file as `script` to html, it was working perfectly. Not sure what you mean actually

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion of `icepickle` to use `refs` instead of `id` in `React` and also using the tutorial:

https://medium.com/@Elijah_Meeks/interactive-applications-with-react-d3-f76f7b3ebc71

I changed `barChart.js` in the following way:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import * as d3 from "d3";
import nvd3 from "nvd3";
var nv = nvd3;

class barChart extends Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.createBarChart = this.createBarChart.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     this.createBarChart()
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.createBarChart()
  }

  createBarChart() {
    const node = this.node
    nv.addGraph(function() {
     var chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart()
        .x(function(d) { return d.label })
        .y(function(d) { return d.value })
        .staggerLabels(true)
        //.staggerLabels(historicalBarChart[0].values.length > 8)
        .showValues(true)
        .duration(250)
        ;
    d3.select(node)
        .datum(exampleData)
        .call(chart);
    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
    return chart;
});
//Each bar represents a single discrete quantity.
function exampleData() {
 return  [
    {
      key: "Cumulative Return",
      values: [
        {
          "label" : "A Label" ,
          "value" : -29.765957771107
        } ,
        {
          "label" : "B Label" ,
          "value" : 0
        } ,
        {
          "label" : "C Label" ,
          "value" : 32.807804682612
        } ,
        {
          "label" : "D Label" ,
          "value" : 196.45946739256
        } ,
        {
          "label" : "E Label" ,
          "value" : 0.19434030906893
        } ,
        {
          "label" : "F Label" ,
          "value" : -98.079782601442
        } ,
        {
          "label" : "G Label" ,
          "value" : -13.925743130903
        } ,
        {
          "label" : "H Label" ,
          "value" : -5.1387322875705
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

}
  }

  render() {
  return <svg ref={node => this.node = node}
  width={500} height={500}>
  </svg>
 }

}

export default barChart
```

And used the element in the main `Index.jsx` view:

```
import React from 'react';
import DefaultLayout from './layouts/default';
import * as d3 from "d3";
import nvd3 from "nvd3";
import barChart from './barChart';

class Index extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <DefaultLayout title={this.props.title}>
          <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>
        <div>
          <barChart/>
        </div>
      </DefaultLayout>
   );
 }
}

module.exports = Index;
```

The error was gone, node was not failing, however, the graph was not rendered still for some other reason. After doing some search I realized that my entry point to `React` is messed up: I thought that node should present `jsx` view `index.jsx` and that should do, but it turned out to be very wrong.

I needed to add `index.html` file into my `public` node static resources folder, then create a new entry `index.js` file (I renamed `index.jsx` into `App.jsx`):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Then, I needed to correct all of the names for the modules for react that started from lowercase (`app -> App; barChart -> BarChart`) to upper case: apparently `React` forces users to use certain naming conventions.

Then I installed `webpack`, bundled all of the `.jsx` files into `bundle.js`, imported it into `index.html` as a `<script>` tag.

And only after doing all of that the project started to work fine.

Comment: Yeah, components and classes should have a name starting with an uppercase, I would go even further in refactoring and implement the `componentShouldUpdate( nextProps )` event to make sure your component only rerenders after it's `props` have changed. Following this, your example data should be a prop on the `BarChart` component, same would go for anything that can be seen as a variable to the BarChart so you can reuse the component as much as possible. Also note that `node` can be null in your current code (eg: when switching routes or just before unmounting)